# In search based application, how to optimise search field?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, search

I am working on the project which is totally based on search. To trigger the search I have 8 fields and one of them is mandatory. I came up with one option to narrow down the search and also to reduce the number of fields to show up in advance.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

I think the user will always come to the system with some motivation. Since this is a search based system, keeping multiple fields might increase the decision time for the user or may mislead his motivation.

I am not sure which one has more advantages over the other.

Do you think search by field will work better and help the user to start the search as quickly as possible.

Comment: it's very similar to a question i asked so I've voted to close. If you think it's different enough we can re-open but I think they're pretty similar.

Comment: @colmcq I think it's little bit different because I have the "search by" dropdown along with the search which might change the answer.

Comment: it sounds you're alluding to a scoped search where you limit the search to a particular area or scope? It's a very common problem that manifest's itself when the back-end is fuzzy and your search algorithm isn't strong.

Comment: Sounds like you've passed from a 'design problem' phase to a 'testing problem' phase, or a 'lack of data' phase. If you knew, for example, that 80% of users used 'Last name' as the primary search field, you could be justified in having that as the default filter in a dropdown selector, and most of the the other fields  By observing users, or even by using some analytics data (to show for example that 4 of the fields are practically never used), you can make better decisions about the how best to present the interaction.